# PrestaShop: How to load a controller inside a controller?

Tags: php, prestashop

How to load a control inside a controller prestashop?
Opencart support load controller inside the controller

```
$data['efgh'] = $this->load->controller('abcd/efgh');
```

So prestashop that support it? If yes then how?

i have a controller Category render custom tpl

```
public function renderList(){

    $tpl = $this->createTemplate('dashboard.tpl');

    // Category
    $categories = GenCategory::getCategories();
    $public_categories = GenCategory::getPublicCategories();
    $unpublic_categories = GenCategory::getUnpublicCategories();

    $tpl->assign(array(
        // Category
        'categories' => $categories,
        'public_categories' => $public_categories,
        'unpublic_categories' => $unpublic_categories,
    ));
    return $tpl->fetch();
}
```

and controller Menu render custom tpl

```
public function renderList(){

    $tpl = $this->createTemplate('menu.tpl');

    $menu = GenMenu::getMenu();

    $tpl->assign(array(
        'menu' => $menu,
    ));
    return $tpl->fetch();
}
```

I need show Menu inside Category.

Comment: It's a controller of your module? Which controller do you need? PrestaShop have only controller, what do you mean for control? Which version of prestashop?

Comment: hi sarcom. i have a controller Category (make by me) and a controller Menu. 2 controller render custom tpl. i need load Menu inside Category to show tpl of Menu inside tpl of Category. i use prestashop 1.6

Comment: Sorry, but it's a contradiction. You have already a controller, at this point fetch also the menu.tpl in the Category controller.
PS: You are using the renderList method in wrong mode :), you have to use the init() method, or initContent() method. It's a frontoffice or backoffice controller? It's a controller of a module?

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you to use the initContent() method, and not the renderList, in this way:

```
public function initContent(){
    // Category
    $categories = GenCategory::getCategories();
    $public_categories = GenCategory::getPublicCategories();
    $unpublic_categories = GenCategory::getUnpublicCategories();

    // Menu
    $menu = $this->genMenu();

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        // Category
        'categories' => $categories,
        'public_categories' => $public_categories,
        'unpublic_categories' => $unpublic_categories,
        // Menu
        'menu' => $menu
    ))
    $this->setTemplate(`rightdirectoryofyourtpl`.'dashboard.tpl');
}

public function genMenu(){
    $menu = GenMenu::getMenu();

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'menu' => $menu,
    ));
    return $this->context->smarty->fetch(`directoryofyourtpl`/menu.tpl)
}
```

Then in your tpl simply 'print' the $menu var

Comment: Otherwise you have to use the PrestaShop hook(s)

Comment: sorry, but it is a backoffice controller, I tried your way and it did not work :)
can you guide me by skype? my skype vdhoangson. thank you very much